# Resolving messages parallely by groups and sequentially in a group

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a few hundred customers. I want to that each customer has a separate SQS queue and a Lambda worker. Because of the below limitations.

1. I request to the legacy third-party system on behalf of my customers. That system requires requesting one at a time sequentially.
2. Jobs don't be created evenly. One customer has a few jobs, others have a lot. But I should process the jobs of customers evenly.

So, jobs should process parallelly by customers (do for several customers at once) and sequentially in a customer.

These workers made of the same source code. Also, every queue has the same message format.

Let me explain a bad case for example. 10 queues can trigger the same lambda. And that lambda limited by 10 concurrencies. By this, I can process parallelly. But If any of queue is empty, other queues have more than one workers. And sequential processing can not be guaranteed.

What is my best option, architecturally speaking to accomplish this? Should I make lambdas for each customer?

Comment: What is the business use-case you are trying to achieve by creating separate SQS queues? Is there a particular problem if you have just one queue? Do jobs take a long time, possibly impacting other customers (how many jobs, how long to process)? Are you trying to separate work for billing purposes? Please edit your question to provide more information.

Comment: Thanks, @JohnRotenstein. Just add some descriptions. If you want more, please comment.

Comment: I am confused. You say that the external system can only process one at a time, but you then have a Lambda concurrency of 10. Which one is the correct bottleneck (restriction)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, external system process one at a time for each customer. I illustrated 10 queues for 10 customers.

Comment: Take a look at [Using the Amazon SQS Message Group ID - Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/using-messagegroupid-property.html). It is a way of creating individual flows within an Amazon SQS FIFO queue, which could be applicable to your customers.

Comment: I am still confused about the flow in your system (limit of 1 vs concurrent Lambdas). If you want some useful advice from StackOverflow contributors, please edit your question to add a lot more detail of what you are attempting to do, what you have tried and what problems you are facing.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, thank for your interest. I will edit my question.